# Load scripts dynamically (angularJs)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have some libraries and dependencies in my angularjs application and I want load all this using only one script because i have three apps using this dependencies.
Actually i have this custom script:

```
var initDependencies = {

  _dependencies: [
    '/path/to/jquery.js', '/path/to/angular.js', 'path/to/bootstrap.js', ...];
  ],

  _currentFolder: '/' + window.location.pathname.split('/')[1],

/**
 * Constructor
 */
  init: function() {
    initDependencies.createDependencies();
  },

/**
 * Retorna el folder actual
 */
  getCurrentFolder : function() {
    return initDependencies._currentFolder;
  },

/**
 * Retorna el array de dependencia
 */
  getDependencies: function() {
    return initDependencies._dependencies; 
  },

/**
 * Crea un nuevo tag <script> con su correspondiente src
 * @param {*} src 
 */
  createNewDependencie : function(src) {
    var myScript = document.createElement("script");
    myScript.type = "text/javascript";
    myScript.src = src;
    console.log('myScript :', myScript);
    document.body.appendChild(myScript);
  },

/**
 * Crea todas las dependencias
 */
  createDependencies: function() {
    for (var dependencie in initDependencies.getDependencies()) {
        var src = this.getCurrentFolder() + initDependencies.getDependencies()[dependencie];
        initDependencies.createNewDependencie(src);
    }
  }
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",initDependencies.init);
```

But I have an error with anothers dependencies into my `dependencies` array, actually i have many errors of type:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'module' of undefined` ( I suppose that `angular` variable does not defined).

How Can I load my dependencies and libraries dynamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These things are usually done by pre-building for specific target via the task runners. **Grunt** or **Gulp** are easy to pick up, run on NodeJS which is easy to set up and is well worth spending an hour or two to set up your building process depending on environment or target deploy. This allows you to have less and smaller JS code files.

NodeJS also has built-in functions to handle most of what you have written above if you wanna ignore the builders you can write the code yourself.

Remember, if you execute stuff in a browser, it does not have permissions to do much with OS's filesystem etc. NodeJS on other hands will have and will allow you to prebuild everything you wanna.

This might be much more simple and faster, since you can uglify, minify and load right away all the js files you are ever gonna need instead loading them later while the user waits for some result and you are loading a couple of MB of libraries at that moment and only then making the request.

The dependency ecosystem also keeps track of versions for you (if you use NPM with NodeJS) which will over time be a huge benefit when it comes down to maintaining your dependencies.

Once set up you can copy the rightly configured dependency file, npm init from it, run builder for specific environment option and voila you set up a new app in 10 seconds using the filesystem organization from old one and setting up a few bits of difference. It also allows you to store all that in a manner that is far more practical when it comes down to versioning. You don't wanna have 1000 dependency files that build your final app in the repository, you wanna have npm and builder configuration in 2 files of plain text.

I hope this has encouraged you to look into it since I believe in any serious project this is the way to go instead of the one you are trying to take.

I would have put this in commentary but is way too long, and stating "use builder to handle that" would sound like explaining nothing.

Comment: Thanks Dante, but I would like made some "lightweight" without to use task manager :)